# How to treat a std::vector like a C buffer efficiently?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

With C buffer, I often do like this:

```
BYTE buffer[MAX_SIZE];
int dataSize = 0;

while (appRunning()) 
{
    dataSize += Receive(buffer + dataSize, MAX_SIZE - dataSize);

    int processedSize = ProcessBuffer(buffer, dataSize);
    ASSERT(processedSize <= dataSize);
    dataSize -= processedSize;
    memmove(buffer, buffer + processedSize, dataSize);
};
```

Is it possible to do so with a `std::vector` without losing much performance?

EDIT:
I have found a way to replace a raw C buffer by a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<BYTE> vbuf;
vbuf.reserve(MAX_SIZE); // allocated at once

while (appRunning()) 
{
    int pendingSize = GetPendingDataSize(); // from a socket
    if (pendingSize > vbuf.capacity())
        pendingSize = vbuf.capacity();

    vbuf.resize(pendingSize);
    int recvSize = Receive(vbuf.data(), vbuf.size());
    ASSERT(recvSize < vbuf.size());
    int processedSize = ProcessBuffer(vbuf.data(), vbuf.size());
    std::rotate(vbuf.begin(), vbuf.begin() + processedSize, vbuf.end());
    vbuf.resize(vbuf.size() - processedSize);
};
```

Actually, in my practical usage, receiving data and processing data may be done in multithread. So by using vector, I do not need to manage buffer's allocation, data size and buffer capacity manually.
Compares to the C buffer, the performance penalty here is at `vbuf.resize()` calls. But I think that penalty is insignificant.
Any better way is appreciated.

Comment: `buffer` is fixed-size. It'll be better to use `std::array<>`.

Comment: As long you're not resizing (growing) the std::vector, you'll lose no performance... You can get a pointer to the raw data with std::vector::data. As ikh pointed out, you could use a std::array and std::array::data. std::array is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays (basically a "c-array").

Comment: @ degski. The purpose I want to move std::vector is to avoid manually managing buffer allocation, buffer size and data size.

Comment: The example you give has MAX_SIZE as the capacity of the buffer. So std::array<BYTE, MAX_SIZE> will do fine and is just the c++ way of BYTE buffer[MAX_SIZE];. Using a std::vector<BYTE> and (if you do) resize it (grow it) will give you loss of performance (due to copying), there is no magic.

Comment: @VietHa so long as the `Receive` function must be used this way, and `ProcessBuffer` requires a contiguous buffer, you're going to be stuck with the same issues. You may as well use an `array` unless you can switch to receiving all-available-data (and preferably processing via iterator pair)

Comment: Your "edit" just makes your code more complicated for no reason

Comment: @ Matt. I haven't got your mean well but I don't see any issue with Receive() and ProcessBuffer() functions since they just access to the valid range of vector's internal buffer. Of course, I can use array well but I prefer vector due to its flexibility.

Comment: Actually the question would be alot better if you wouldn't ask how to use `vector` the way you want it to use, but rather which data structure to use instead of a c-array to accomplish this task. By the looks of it stream like semantics are better suitable.

Comment: I am somewhat confused. As far as I understood it, [C++11 made the return value of `data()` **constant**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), so it cannot be used this way *at all*...?!?

Answer (score 2):

When receiving messages over a TCP connection the last message in the buffer may be incomplete. After processing complete messages, people often just `memmove` that last incomplete message to the beginning of the buffer.

Another strategy is to use a "smart" ring-buffer to avoid that `memmove` and also avoid data wrapping over the ring buffer thus creating discontinuity. To make a "smart" ring-buffer allocate memory for the buffer using `mmap` and map the same region of pages twice with no gaps in between. This way reading past the end of the buffer continues reading it from the start, preventing the discontinuity inherent when using a regular ring-buffer.

---

Using `std::vector` for network buffers is less than ideal because resizing a vector initialises its elements that are later overwritten by `recv` call. That initialization is unnecessary for such buffers.

Comment: For those interested by the `mmap()` optimization, a programmer wrote a [`queue.c`](https://github.com/le1ca/toy-queue/) available on Github.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Well, your queue conflates the smart ring-buffer with locking. Locking may be unnecessary for many applications.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, C arrays have been for the most parts replaced by [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<BYTE, MAX_SIZE> buffer;
```

It is only a thin wrapper around C arrays. So, from a performance perspective, you do not loose anything. There are nicer to work with, however.

But like C arrays, they only work for fixed-time arrays where the size is known at compile time. It is not possible to resize them. But if I read your question correctly, you do not need that extra flexibility, here.

Comment: C11 has VLAs, but it's indeed not relevant for that question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want behavior similar to C (that is, you want to guarantee the vector won't ever free or allocate more memory for the underlying vector), a nice solution is to use [Boost's static_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.static_vector). It statically allocates the underlying buffer but otherwise it acts like a normal vector.

```
boost::static_vector<BYTE, MAX_SIZE> buffer;
```

For this type of activity, however, you might also look into [std::queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) or [boost::cirular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) and see if one of those fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to replace it with `std::vector`, or equivalently `std::array`. You don't need to resize the vector, so don't.

```
std::vector<BYTE> buffer(MAX_SIZE);
BYTE * start = buffer.data();
int dataSize = 0;

while (appRunning()) 
{
    dataSize += Receive(start, MAX_SIZE - dataSize);

    int processedSize = ProcessBuffer(buffer.data(), dataSize);
    ASSERT(processedSize <= dataSize);
    dataSize -= processedSize;
    start = std::copy_n(buffer.data() + processedSize, dataSize, buffer.data());
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Writing from memory, please check if it works for you:

```
std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
buffer.reserve(MAX_SIZE);
int dataSize = 0;

while (appRunning()) 
{
    dataSize += Receive(&buffer[0] + dataSize, MAX_SIZE - dataSize);

    int processedSize = ProcessBuffer(&buffer[0], dataSize);
    ASSERT(processedSize <= dataSize);
    dataSize -= processedSize;
    memmove(&buffer[0], &buffer[0] + processedSize, dataSize);
};
```

Comment: It should be `buffer.resize(MAX_SIZE);`. (or just use constructor `std::vector<BYTE> buffer(MAX_SIZE);`

Comment: @lgromanowski. Your solution is fine but the buffer.size() does not present the current data size of the buffer which is useful in case receiving data and processing data are asynchronous.

Comment: @VietHa Instead we can use `dataSize`. It's not such a good design, but it's not so bad - in case of migration from C.